# Response Caching Middleware and Load Balancing on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc

We are using the [ResponseCaching Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in an ASP.NET Core v3.1 for API endpoints. We're running in a load-balanced environment on AWS.

Here's a sample use of the `ResponseCache` attribute usage:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "productId" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string productId) {
   // ...
}
```

This seems to be working fine.

When a client wants to bust the cache, the client simply sends an HTTP header:

```
cache-control: no-cache;
```

Here's what I want to verify: We have a load-balanced environment on AWS. If the client resets the cache as shown above, that'll only affect one instance/node on AWS, right? For example, client-1 can send a `cache-control: no-cache` to reset the cache but a moment later client-2 can still potentially see the old values if client-2's request is routed to a different server from that of client-1. Is that right?

What is the general solution to caching in a load-balanced environment like this? Do we have to use something like Redis or is there something on AWS?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about exactly. `Cache-Control` is a *response* header. It's for the server to give instructions to the client, not the other way around. The client cannot "bust" the server's cache, it would be kind of scary if they could.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, ```Cache-Control``` is both a Response *and* Request header.

Comment: @ChrisPratt it is a client side header as well, but I am pretty sure most caching systems I have used have ignored it from the client

Comment: @jordanm: The ```ResponseCaching``` middleware does not ignore the ```cache-control``` header from the client. It does what the  HTTP spec says it should do: "The 'no-cache' request directive indicates that a cache MUST NOT use  a stored response to satisfy the request without successful validation on the origin server."